# Udev does not rename usb ethernet device

Tags: arch-linux, udev, ethernet, android, usb-device

I'm using Arch Linux, Udev v234, SystemD v234.11-8.

I have a laptop which runs Arch Linux, and a Nexus 5 android phone which catches WiFi signal better than my laptop. I want my laptop to automatically connect to the internet when I plug in the phone through USB tethering. For this to work I have tried a few things:

1. I have created this (and the only) udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-nexus-plugged.rules`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee2", IMPORT="/lib/udev/rename_netiface %k hello", RUN+="/home/babken/test/adb-enable-tethering"
   ```

   I expect udev to rename my device to `hello`, but it still creates a random name. What am I doing wrong?

   I know this rule is matching because my script gets executed.
2. I have created 2 udev rules. First one is for enabling USB tethering by remoting into my phone and enabling tethering:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee*",  RUN+="/home/babken/test/adb-enable-tethering"
   ```

   Second rule should rename the ethernet name from random name of `enp0setc` to `hello`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="enp0s29u1u2", ATTR{address}=="6a:e7:28:13:45:f7", NAME="hello", RUN+="/bin/touch /tmp/hello"
   ```

   This second rule does not even get triggered, it does not create `/tmp/hello` file.

   Interestingly enough if I run `udevadm test /sys/class/net/enp0s29u1u2` this second rule DOES get triggered and my device DOES rename to `hello`. But not when I unplug/replug my phone. Why does this rule not trigger then?

I always reload udev rules by running `sudo udevadm control --reload` after making changes to udev rules.

Here are my journalctl logs when I plug in the device:

```
Aug 25 15:41:44 lenovo-laptop kernel: usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 38 using ehci-pci
Aug 25 15:41:49 lenovo-laptop kernel: usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 38
Aug 25 15:41:49 lenovo-laptop kernel: usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 39 using ehci-pci
Aug 25 15:41:49 lenovo-laptop kernel: rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, RNDIS device, c6:d5:df:ba:ba:4d
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop systemd-udevd[20464]: Process '/home/babken/test/adb-enable-tethering' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop systemd-udevd[20710]: Process '/home/babken/test/adb-enable-tethering' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop mtp-probe[20778]: checking bus 2, device 39: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop mtp-probe[20778]: bus: 2, device: 39 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop systemd-udevd[20464]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop kernel: rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 enp0s29u1u2: renamed from usb0
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: waiting for carrier
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: waiting for carrier
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: carrier acquired
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: IAID 28:13:45:f7
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: adding address fe80::5f59:ada0:7eae:987b
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: soliciting an IPv6 router
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop ifplugd(enp0s29u1u2)[12486]: Link beat detected.
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: rebinding lease of 192.168.42.150
Aug 25 15:41:50 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: probing address 192.168.42.150/24
Aug 25 15:41:51 lenovo-laptop ifplugd(enp0s29u1u2)[12486]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action enp0s29u1u2 up'.
Aug 25 15:41:51 lenovo-laptop ifplugd(enp0s29u1u2)[12486]: Program executed successfully.
Aug 25 15:41:56 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: leased 192.168.42.150 for 3600 seconds
Aug 25 15:41:56 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: adding route to 192.168.42.0/24
Aug 25 15:41:56 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: adding default route via 192.168.42.129
Aug 25 15:42:03 lenovo-laptop dhcpcd[3516]: enp0s29u1u2: no IPv6 Routers available
```

Output of `udevadm info -a /sys/class/net/enp0s29u1u2`:

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/net/enp0s29u1u2':
    KERNEL=="enp0s29u1u2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="net"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{addr_assign_type}=="3"
    ATTR{addr_len}=="6"
    ATTR{address}=="6a:e7:28:13:45:f7"
    ATTR{broadcast}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
    ATTR{carrier}=="1"
    ATTR{carrier_changes}=="0"
    ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0"
    ATTR{dev_port}=="0"
    ATTR{dormant}=="0"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x1003"
    ATTR{gro_flush_timeout}=="0"
    ATTR{ifalias}==""
    ATTR{ifindex}=="36"
    ATTR{iflink}=="36"
    ATTR{link_mode}=="0"
    ATTR{mtu}=="1500"
    ATTR{name_assign_type}=="4"
    ATTR{netdev_group}=="0"
    ATTR{operstate}=="unknown"
    ATTR{proto_down}=="0"
    ATTR{tx_queue_len}=="1000"
    ATTR{type}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1.2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="rndis_host"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="e0"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="03"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="RNDIS Communications Control"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2':
    KERNELS=="2-1.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 3"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0232"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="68"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee4"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="LGE"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="Nexus 5"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0831bd3b21320609"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="685"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="152578"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0412"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.12.8-2-ARCH ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="27919"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1c26"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="23"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x05"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3975"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: I don't understand: Is your script supposed to do the renaming or do you want udev to do the renaming? If your script is supposed to do so, then provide it, please.

Comment: You specified a `%k` in the `IMPORT` but you have *only* "upward" matches (ones with "S") in the udev rule. How is udev suppose to know which kernel name you are referring to?

Comment: @fragwürdig Udev is supposed to do the renaming with `IMPORT=` command.

Comment: @TomYan I don't know I am new to udev.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following rule to do the renaming part. Feel free to modify things to get your scripts running:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee2", NAME="hallo"
```

This rule is derived from [that](https://superuser.com/questions/801846/rename-usb-network-interface-based-on-location) one.

If that does not work then you should watch out for udev rules that were created by your system automatically. For example, my Debian system uses the following rule to manage the wifi interface (the rule quoted here is a bit tweaked, see below):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="c0:f8:da:03:c1:a8", NAME="wlan2"
```

Note the MAC address `c0:f8:da:03:c1:a8` that was inserted. Maybe something similar helps you to create your custom rule that renames your device accordingly.

**Edit:** Second rule provided above is now essentially cut down to the one mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Tips_and_tricks) (as also noted by Tom Yan down in the comments).

Comment: That didn't work. I guess because this is a android usb device which creates a child ethernet device which has subsystem="usb". I updated original post with details. I have also tried with subsystem="usb" and that didn't work either.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan No. Note that `SUBSYSTEM` is not the same as `SUBSYSTEMS`. Same case for `ATTR`/`ATTRS`. Simply put, `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee2"` means "match a net device that is under the device `18d1:4ee2`. You can add `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb"` (note the `S`es) to make it it more precise I suppose, though it may not be necessary; since the device you want to match is the net interface, so `SUBSYSTEM=="net"` (no `S`) is correct.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan from your udevadm info output, apparently you made a mistake. It's `ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee4"`, but not `ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee2"`

Comment: @TomYan It's a bit more complicated, my Nexus device has `4ee2` in `debug` mode (i.e. when just plugged in), and when the script runs it switches idProduct to `4ee4` when it's in `debug + tether` mode.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan well you can use a glob for that case I think (`4ee*`). It might even be alright to omit the idProduct match.

Comment: I am a bit unsure about the second rule in the answer btw. Some of the matches seems pointless and potentially problematic. I would probably trim it to this (and adapt to the OP's case) : `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="6a:e7:28:13:45:f7", NAME="hello"` (optionally adding `KERNEL=="enp0s29u1u2"`)

Comment: @TomYan OK I figured I need 2 rules, one to enable tethering and "plug in" the ethernet interface: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee*",  RUN+="/home/babken/test/adb-enable-tethering"` (which works) and the second one to rename the ethernet interface: `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="6a:e7:28:13:45:f7", NAME="hello", RUN+="/bin/touch /tmp/hello"` but my second rule is not getting triggered, even though my mac address is right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan Not sure. So no `/tmp/hello` created? (Does `which touch` give you `/bin/touch`?) What if you add `KERNEL=="enp0s29u1u2"` or `KERNEL=="en*"`?

Comment: @TomYan No `/tmp/hello` is not created and yes `/bin/touch` exists. Interestingly enough when I run `udevadm test /sys/class/net/enp0s29u1u2` it does rename device to `hello`. I have tried this second rule per your suggestion (also with `en*`) and it doesn't trigger: `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="enp0s29u1u2", ATTR{address}=="6a:e7:28:13:45:f7", NAME="hello", RUN+="/bin/touch /tmp/hello"`.

Comment: @TomYan I have added these and other findings to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this answer doesn't solve my problem of Udev rule not getting triggered. However since my original goal was to get a consistent ethernet device name when I plug it in into different ports, this solution does it's job.

It turns out Udev overrides my configuration, so I simply disabled it's network rules:

```
 # ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

Now my device is named `usb0` all the time. See [Revert to_traditional device names](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Revert_to_traditional_device_names).

Answer (score 0):

I came around this question when I wanted to configure automatic configuration for my FairPhone. This should be limited to my Fairphone as I trust only my devices. So I want to rename only the network device provided by my Fairphone to something that can be recognised by ifup/ifdown.

The suggestions above helped me to get it running.

There are are two things one should keep in mind:

1. My fairphone generates several changing MAC addresses for the network device. So matching the ethernet address does not work at all.
2. The `SUBSYSTEM=="net"` gets triggered only after the USB tethering has been enabled in Android, and the network interface has been created.

The following rule seems to work for me:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Hersteller", ATTRS{idProduct}=="dead", ATTRS{idVendor}=="beef", ATTRS{serial}=="deadbeef", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="usb*", NAME="mydevname0"
```

you have to change the fields according to your setup.